# In C#, How can I dynamically pass T into services.AddHostedService<T>()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, type-parameter, ihostedservice

I have a webservice with multiple hosted services.

I want to be able to turn them on and off through "appSettings.json".

In "StartUp.cs", I populate an instance of

```
    public class HostedServiceSettings
    {
        public StateOfUse BuildMontageTasks { get; init; }
        public StateOfUse BuildTasksFromFileCreations { get; init; }
        public StateOfUse BusinessEventPuller { get; init; }
        public StateOfUse FieldServiceAppointmentChanges { get; init; }
        public StateOfUse MvtBriefingCleanupLoop { get; init; }
        public StateOfUse SfCacheFileListener { get; init; }
        public StateOfUse TaskWorker { get; init; }
    }
```

`StateOfUse` is this enum:

```
    public enum StateOfUse
    {
        Inactive,
        Active
    }
```

and each property corresponds to a hosted service.

Back in the `StartUp` class, I've added the following method:

```
        private void AddHostedServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            HostedServiceSettings settings = Configure<HostedServiceSettings>(services, "HostedServices");
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(HostedServiceSettings).GetProperties())
            {
                StateOfUse stateOfUse = (StateOfUse)property.GetValue(settings);
                if (stateOfUse.IsActive())
                {
                    string hostedServiceName = $"PraxedoIntegration.{property.Name}HostedService";
                    Type hostedServiceType = Type.GetType(hostedServiceName);

                    Type type = typeof(IServiceCollection);
                    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("IServiceCollection.AddHostedService");
                    MethodInfo genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(hostedServiceType);
                    genericMethod.Invoke(services, null);
                }
            }
        }
```

This fails because `MethodInfo methodInfo` resolves to null and thus an exception will be thrown in the next line.  The method `IServiceCollection.AddHostedService<THostedService>()` is a static method inculded in "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" in the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace in `public static class ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions`.  (I don't use `nameof` in the code because that is not supported for extension methods. :-( )

Is it possible to access this method through generics?
If so, how?

Comment: You're trying to register the services based on configuration. Why not do what you *asked* instead - turn them on/off based on configuration? Inject the config options into the services and have them do nothing unless they're switched on.

Comment: There's no need for dynamic hoopla in any case, even if you did need dynamic service types -- the methods are extension methods on the basic functionality of `IServiceCollection`, which is just a `Collection` of `ServiceDescriptor`s. Nothing prevents you from calling `Add` directly with a manually constructed `ServiceDescriptor` (although, admittedly, figuring the layer cake of the extension methods in terms of implementation can be tricky).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, because then I need to duplicate the logic in all the services and pollute the services with data they don't need to _run_.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Not entirely clear how to do that, but relying on implementation details sounds not only tricky but potentially dangerous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out I could solve the problem most simply by wrapping the extension method in a local method, like:

```
        private void AddHostedServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            HostedServiceSettings settings = Configure<HostedServiceSettings>(services, "HostedServices");
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(HostedServiceSettings).GetProperties())
            {
                StateOfUse stateOfUse = (StateOfUse)property.GetValue(settings);
                if (stateOfUse.IsActive())
                {
                    string hostedServiceName = $"PraxedoIntegration.{property.Name}HostedService";
                    Type hostedServiceType = Type.GetType(hostedServiceName);

                    Type type = typeof(Startup);
                    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("AddHostedService");
                    MethodInfo genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(hostedServiceType);
                    genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { services });
                }
            }
        }

        // Needed as a work-arround because we can't call the extension method with reflection.
        public IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(IServiceCollection services)
            where THostedService : class, IHostedService =>
                services.AddHostedService<THostedService>();
```

Alternative, it's been drawn to my attention, in this instance, the implementation details for `AddHostedService()` are known and it is simply a wrapper (arguably "syntactic sugar") for `AddTransient()`, so I could avoid the reflection by doing this:

```
        private void AddHostedServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            HostedServiceSettings settings = Configure<HostedServiceSettings>(services, "HostedServices");
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(HostedServiceSettings).GetProperties())
            {
                StateOfUse stateOfUse = (StateOfUse)property.GetValue(settings);
                if (stateOfUse.IsActive())
                {
                    string hostedServiceName = $"PraxedoIntegration.{property.Name}HostedService";
                    Type hostedServiceType = Type.GetType(hostedServiceName);

                    services.AddTransient(typeof(IHostedService), hostedServiceType);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [overload of `AddHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions_AddHostedService__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__) which takes an `implementationFactory` registering each service, but if inactive returns a null implementation

```
services.AddHostedService<ServiceA>( (services => {
     HostedServiceSettings settings = Configure<HostedServiceSettings>(services, "HostedServices");
     if(settings.IsServiceAActive())
         return new ServiceA();
     return NullService();      
})
```

Comment: But I still would have the same problem to populate the Type parameter.

Comment: @BrianKessler well, the idea was just register them all - presumably you have a finite set matching the settings class - but the ones which are disabled just get a null implementation

Comment: What I'm _really_ trying to do here is remove the need to itemize the same information (the supported services) in both the Configuration and the StartUp.  If the StartUp can derive the types for the services, I don't need to itemize them there.    :-)